# How to use switch-case on pandas dataframe having a column containing sets as value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe (variable name **box_status**) in which one column contains `SET` values:

```
+-----------------------+-------------------------+
|             zone_name |                   status|
+-----------------------+-------------------------+
|          D7_BATCH_BOX |            {NOT_STARTED}|
|    BUS_BATCH_AMER_BOX | {NOT_STARTED, COMPLETED}|
|    BUS_BATCH_AUST_BOX | {NOT_STARTED, COMPLETED}|
|    DOM_BATCH_AMER_BOX |  {NOT_LOADED, COMPLETED}|
|    DOM_BATCH_AUST_BOX |  {NOT_LOADED, COMPLETED}|
|    DOM_BATCH_CAND_BOX |  {NOT_LOADED, COMPLETED}|
|         SIT_BATCH_BOX |            {NOT_STARTED}|
|        SHORT_FEES_BOX |              {COMPLETED}|
+-----------------------+-------------------------+
```

I need to add one more column using the switch-case condition based on column **status**, like if *status* column contains values "NOT_STARTED" and "COMPLETED", then new column will contain "RUNNING".
I have used the code below, where I have created sets for each condition, and trying to use it with `issubset()` but getting error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "status_mailer_new.py", line 211, in <module>
    box_status["zone_status"] = np.where(comp_set.issubset(box_status["status"]), "COMPLETED",
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

Code is:

```
comp_set = {"COMPLETED"}
runn_set = {"COMPLETED","NOT_STARTED"}
yet_to_start_set = {"NOT_STARTED"}
fail_set1 = {"NOT_STARTED","NOT_LOADED"}
fail_set2 = {"NOT_LOADED","COMPLETED"}
fail_set3 = {"NOT_LOADED"}
box_status["zone_status"] = np.where(comp_set.issubset(box_status["status"]), "COMPLETED",
                           np.where(runn_set.issubset(box_status["status"]), "RUNNING",
                           np.where(yet_to_start_set.issubset(box_status["status"]), "YET TO START",
                           np.where(fail_set1.issubset(box_status["status"]),"ERROR",
                           np.where(fail_set2.issubset(box_status["status"]),"ERROR",
                           np.where(fail_set3.issubset(box_status["status"]),"ERROR","ERROR"))))))
```

Comment: Both `comp_set` and `runn_set` are the subsets of `{"COMPLETED","NOT_STARTED"}`. So why the status of those rows is `RUNNING` and not `COMPLETED`? I think equality is more appropriate here than looking for a subset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to find where a given set is equal to the sets in `status` rather than it is its subset. You can create another dataframe with respective conditions and merge it with the main dataframe. However, you need to turn the sets into strings to be able to perform `merge`:

```
status_dict =  {
'comp_set' : {"COMPLETED"},
'runn_set' : {"COMPLETED","NOT_STARTED"},
'yet_to_start_set' : {"NOT_STARTED"},
'fail_set1' : {"NOT_STARTED","NOT_LOADED"},
'fail_set2' : {"NOT_LOADED","COMPLETED"},
'fail_set3' : {"NOT_LOADED"}}

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(status_dict.items())
df2.columns = ['new_col', 'status']

# change dtypes
df['status'] = df['status'].astype(str)
df2['status'] = df2['status'].astype(str)

#finally merge

new_df = df.merge(df2, on='status', how='left')
```

Output:

```
          status                     new_col
0   {'NOT_STARTED'}             yet_to_start_set
1   {'COMPLETED', 'NOT_STARTED'}    runn_set
2   {'COMPLETED', 'NOT_STARTED'}    runn_set
3   {'COMPLETED', 'NOT_LOADED'} fail_set2
4   {'COMPLETED', 'NOT_LOADED'} fail_set2
5   {'COMPLETED', 'NOT_LOADED'} fail_set2
6   {'NOT_STARTED'}             yet_to_start_set
7   {'COMPLETED'}               comp_set
```

You can turn 'string sets' to actual sets with `eval`:

```
new_df['status'] = new_df['status'].agg(eval)
```